# Creating a Loading view in .NET Core / Change view without returning c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, loading

I am working on a website created in .NET Core (using the full .NET Framework) that uses background tasks to get a devices list.

I want to display a loading "view" like [this](https://codepen.io/jczimm/pen/vEBpoL) while the task is getting data from another PC (using [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) requests) and then, when the task is completed I want to display the table with the devices. How can I do that?

Here is a little piece of my code:

```
public class DeviceController : Controller {

    public IActionResult Index() {

        if (DataSyncronizer.getDeviceListTask.Status == TaskStatus.Running) {

            // TODO Show the loading screen here.

            // return this.View("Loading");
        }

        if (DataSyncronizer.getDeviceListTask.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted) {
            ViewData["ErrorTitle"] = "Errore di sincronizzazione";
            ViewData["ErrorText"] = "Cannot get devices";
            return this.View("Error");
        }

        if (DataSyncronizer.getDeviceListTask.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled) {
            ViewData["ErrorTitle"] = "Errore di sincronizzazione";
            ViewData["ErrorText"] = "";
            return this.View("Error");
        }

        return this.View(DataSyncronizer.Devices);
    }
```

And this is the function that gets the device list:

```
public static class DataSyncronizer {

    public static Task<List<Device>> getDeviceListTask { get; private set; }
    public static List<Device> Devices = new List<Device>();

    public static Task UpdateDevices() {

        getDeviceListTask = new Task<List<Device>>(() =>
                      Device.GetMyDevicesList(meUser));

        getDeviceListTask.ContinueWith((result) => {
                DataSyncronizer.Devices = result.Result;
            }, TaskScheduler.Current);

        getDeviceListTask.Start();
        return getDeviceListTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You could display the loader right before you call UpdateDevices().**

> add this to the end of your TASK

```
.ContinueWith(t => "Function to hide loader");
```

Example

```
var webTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    try 
    { 
        wcf.UploadMotionDynamicRaw(bytes);  //my web service
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //deal with error
    }
}).ContinueWith(t => "Function to hide loader");
```

Comment: Yes I could do it but I don't want to because the user might do something else while the list of devices is still loading. I just want to display the loading view if the user asks for the devices list and it is not ready yet.

Comment: Modified the post for a solution that might help

Comment: Yes but how can I hide the loader (redirecting to /Devices/List) without returning an IActionResult?

Comment: You would have to return a result. How would the client ever know if the server is done processing it's request?

Comment: You would have to return a result. How would the client ever know if the server is done processing it's request? In your result you need to tell the client to hide the loader.